# how can we create a node publishing a random data using a class and without using a callback function

Tags: ros, rosnode, ros-kinetic, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to create a publisher node without using a callback function as the title explains. Have you guys any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297900/how-can-we-create-a-node-publishing-a-random-data-using-a-class-and-without-using-a-callback-function/) by [samo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34944/samo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2018-07-19**:
You could read the documentation and tutorials and come back as soon as you run into a real problem.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-19**:
Callbacks are used with the subscribers to get messages from topics, so just check the [ros publisher tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest you go through [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials), and get basic grasp of what callbacks are for and how publishers work.

---

Originally posted by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) with karma: 685 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0